# How much is the (probability / likelihood) of something?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, difference, expressions

How do you normally ask about the probability / likelihood of something in English?

**Example:**

The number of artificial satellites is increasing and the gravitational force is acting up on them. But the question is that:

> a. **How much is the probability of** striking of artificial satellites in space? 
>   b. **How much is the likelihood** of striking of artificial satellites in space?

Please kindly let me know whether both of these expressions are fixed or there is only one correct expression between them. If so, which one is that? Is there any better expression to ask about it in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more idiomatic expression is
"What is the probability/likelihood of collision between artificial satellites in space."

Another possible way to express the same idea is
"How likely/probable is a collision between artificial satellites."

I suggest "... collision ... between ..." because "striking of" might mean that someone is shooting at the satellites, and one is asking about the likelihood of hitting them.

Comment: Thank you @Jack O'Flaherty. Just out of curiosity; I have encountered many times to "there is a **little** (probability / likelihood) for something". Can we substitute it for "there is a **low** (probability / likelihood) for something" as an answer to the question?

Comment: @A-friend I don't think I've heard "a little probability", but I've heard "there is little probability". In any case, your suggestion of "a low probability" is quite idiomatic.